# Getting the underlying type of slice passed as type argument to a type parameter in the receiver of a method

Tags: go, generics, functional-programming

I am creating a data structure using Go generics.

The use case is to write a Reduce function that takes a slice of a defined type, applies a reduce function to each element of the slice and returns a value of the defined type.

```
type MyType[T any] struct{
    I T
}

// I want to write something like this
func (m *MyType[[]T]) Reduce(init T, fnReduce func(T, T)T) (*MyType[T]) {
    acc := init
    for _, v := range m.I {
        acc = fnReduce(acc, v)
    }
    return &MyType[T]{I : acc}

}
```

Go compiler does not allow to give the type parameter to the receiver as:
`m *MyType[[]T]`

What is a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a method on a slice to reduce it, define `MyStruct` as a slice of `T`:

```golang
type MyType[T any] []T

func (m MyType[T]) Reduce(init T, fnReduce func(acc, elem T) (result T)) T {
    res := init
    for _, v := range m {
        res = fnReduce(res, v)
    }
    return res
}
```

Here an example on the [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/VqpYQh0nPWZ?v=).

---

In case you need to be able to add other fields to `MyStruct` apart from the slice itself, a struct with a field containing the slice is also an option. (`New` func to populate the private slice field from outside the package.)

```golang
func NewMyType[T any](sl []T) MyType[T] {
    return MyType[T]{sl: sl}
}

type MyType[T any] struct {
    sl []T
}

func (m MyType[T]) Reduce(init T, fnReduce func(acc, elem T) (result T)) T {
    res := init
    for _, v := range m.sl {
        res = fnReduce(res, v)
    }
    return res
}
```

---

On the issue stated in the comment:

1. First idea is to call a reduce function whenever the need is identified to reduce the data. This works if there is a place where we know the data is of type slice. If that is never the case (all code is generic), then have a look at option 2).

```golang
func reduce[T any](sl []T, init T, fnReduce func(acc, elem T) (result T)) T {
    res := init
    for _, v := range sl {
        res = fnReduce(res, v)
    }
    return res 
}
```

2. The second idea is to have a old fashioned interface that is implemented differently for different data types.

```golang
type MyI[T any] interface {
    Reduce(init T, reduce func(acc, elem T) (result T)) T
}

type MySliceType[T any] struct {
    data []T
}

func (m MySliceType[T]) Reduce(init T, reduce func(acc, elem T) T) T {
    res := init
    for _, v := range m.data {
        res = reduce(res, v)
    }
    return res
}

type MyType[T any] struct {
    data T
}

func (m MyType[T]) Reduce( T,  func(acc, elem T) T) T {
    return m.data
}
```

We have a common `Reduce` function here, just in case we don't have a slice it just return `m.data`. If we have a slice, it actually applies the reduce function.

(The example doesn't make too much sense, but I hope the idea comes across.)